# Numpy triu generates nan when called on matrices with infinite values

Tags: python, numpy

Just found some unexpected behaviour in Numpy 1.8.1 in the triu function.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((4, 4))
a[1:, 2] = np.inf
a
>>>array([[  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
          [ inf,   0.,   0.,   0.],
          [ inf,   0.,   0.,   0.],
          [ inf,   0.,   0.,   0.]])

np.triu(a)
>>>array([[  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
          [ nan,   0.,   0.,   0.],
          [ nan,   0.,   0.,   0.],
          [ nan,   0.,   0.,   0.]])
```

Would this behaviour ever be desirable?  Or shall I file a bug report?

**Edit**

I raised an [issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4859) on the Numpy github page

Comment: This is now solved [in numpy master](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/4861), but it won't be in an official release until 1.10, I'm afraid.

Comment: Very quick work, thanks for that.  I'll use the workaround until then.

Comment: You may want to look at [the new numpy implementation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/twodim_base.py#L421), which is very sleek, and a little faster than what has been discussed in the answers to this question. `triu(a, k)` would simply be `np.where(np.tri(*a.shape, k=k-1, dtype=bool), 0, a)`, and `tril(a, k)` is `np.where(np.tri(*a.shape, k=k, dtype=bool), arr, 0)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 1. Explanation

Looks like you ignored the `RuntimeWarning`:

```
>>> np.triu(a)
twodim_base.py:450: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
  out = multiply((1 - tri(m.shape[0], m.shape[1], k - 1, dtype=m.dtype)), m)
```

The [source code for `numpy.triu`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/twodim_base.py#L458) is as follows:

```
def triu(m, k=0):
    m = asanyarray(m)
    out = multiply((1 - tri(m.shape[0], m.shape[1], k - 1, dtype=m.dtype)), m)
    return out
```

This uses [`numpy.tri`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tri.html) to get an array with ones below the diagonal and zeros above, and subtracts this from 1 to get an array with zeros below the diagonal and ones above:

```
>>> 1 - np.tri(4, 4, -1)
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Then it multiplies this element-wise with the original array. So where the original array has `inf`, the result has `inf * 0` which is NaN.

#### 2. Workaround

Use [`numpy.tril_indices`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tril_indices.html) to generate the indices of the lower triangle, and set all those entries to zero:

```
>>> a = np.ones((4, 4))
>>> a[1:, 0] = np.inf
>>> a
array([[  1.,   1.,   1.,   1.],
       [ inf,   1.,   1.,   1.],
       [ inf,   1.,   1.,   1.],
       [ inf,   1.,   1.,   1.]])
>>> a[np.tril_indices(4, -1)] = 0
>>> a
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

(Depending on what you are going to do with `a`, you might want to take a copy before zeroing these entries.)

Comment: Strange - I didn't see the warning.  I guess they must be suppressed.  Good spot.  All the same, this isn't really desirable behaviour, right?

Comment: @Gabriel: This is a bug.  It would at least need to be documented.

Comment: I put some changes to that code not that long ago to speed it up, but the overall multiplication method stayed the same. I looked into using boolean indexing instead of multiplication, which seemes a more reasonable solution, but it slows things down about 10%, so it stayed the same. This test case gives a good argument for revisiting that decision, though...

Comment: As for your workaround, it is (probably much) faster to do: `mask = ~np.tri(*a.shape, dtype=bool); a[mask] = 0`, but yes, that seems the way to overcome this issue.